# Sentry + Raven, HTTP Error 401: UNAUTHORIZED

Tags: python, django, haproxy, sentry, raven

I have a [Sentry](http://sentry.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) application, running correctly on the url: mydomain.com:11011.

I have a project created with the CDN: http://XXX:YYY@mydomain.com:11011/2

This url is served with HAProxy with this configuration:

```
listen sentry *:11011
    mode tcp
    server app1 localhost:9005 maxconn 32
```

The configuration of sentry:

```
SENTRY_KEY = 'foo'
SENTRY_PUBLIC = True
SENTRY_URL_PREFIX = 'http://mydomain.com:11011'  # No trailing slash!
SENTRY_WEB_HOST = 'localhost'
SENTRY_WEB_PORT = 9005
SENTRY_WEB_OPTIONS = {
    'workers': 1, # the number of gunicorn workers
    'worker_class': 'gevent',
}
```

But I have a problem with authentication when I try Raven test, from the same server:

```
$ raven test http://XXX:YYY@mydomain.com:11011/2
HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: UNAUTHORIZED
```

Also fails:

```
$ raven test http://XXX:YYY@localhost:9005/2
HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: UNAUTHORIZED
```

What could be the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was the different versions of raven on the client and server

In the Sentry server:

```
raven==1.8.4
sentry==4.4.5
```

In the django application:

```
raven==1.9.1
```

To fix this, do the following, in django application.

```
pip uninstall raven
pip install raven==1.8.4
```